# Does Snell's window (the optical man-hole) work both ways?

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

My physics book states: Just because you can see a fish under water (you are above; the fish is below) doesn't mean the fish can see you due to Snell's window.

Is this true? I would have assumed that someone standing in a boat surrounded by water would also have a Snell's window. Surely if light can travel from the fish to your eye then it can also make the reverse journey.

Comment: http://scienceblogs.com/principles/2013/07/25/reflecting-totally-or-why-the-pool-looks-shiny-from-underwater/  is related but I think there will be a duplicate here if you search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, light travels the reverse way. You cannot realize an optical diode with linear optical elements in absence of fields other the light itself. (Faraday effect with static magnetic field is needed for an optical diode for instance).

Most likely the textbook refers to the case where one *practically* cannot see the fish due to strong light coming through the (other) reflection path. But this is due to limited dynamic range of our vision. The light paths are still perfectly reversible.